# How to generate same random arrays while using np.random.normal()

Tags: python, numpy, random

```
X_p=np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=(100,2))
X_n=np.random.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(50,2))
plt.scatter(X_p[:,0],X_p[:,1])
plt.scatter(X_n[:,0],X_n[:,1],color='red')
plt.show()
```

this code generates different plot everytime we run it.
Can someone tell me is there a way to generate same data always with given std and mean

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found a way

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X_p=rng.normal(0,0.05,size=(100,2))
X_n=rng.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(50,2))
plt.scatter(X_p[:,0],X_p[:,1])
plt.scatter(X_n[:,0],X_n[:,1],color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now each and every time you run this code, you'll get the same output

Answer (score 0):

You must fix the seed used by the pseudorandom number generator algorithms. To do so in Numpy, you may use the [`np.random.seed()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy-random-seed) function (see caveats therein - it seems a bit outdated).

Comment: The `numpy` guide on [`random`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html) has more details on setting seeds beyond the legacy `np.random.seed`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware but like here I want to produce the data by setting both it's mean and variance.